# MySQL not run on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I have had massive issues installing MySQL I now gave it installed but it refuses to start. When I run:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

return:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since lun 2016-08-29 09:25:31 CEST; 38min ago
Process: 2735 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ago 29 09:25:31 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
ago 29 09:25:31 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
ago 29 09:25:31 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ago 29 09:25:31 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
ago 29 09:25:31 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
ago 29 09:25:31 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
ago 29 09:25:31 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Any ideas how I can find out what's happening?

Comment: Did you try using `journalctl` to read the mysql logs and see if there is more useful info there?  (And/or check the logs under `/var/log/` if you prefer.)

Comment: post output of journalctl -xn

Comment: I am having the same issue following an electrical outage.... here's the journalctl -xn dump

http://pastebin.com/AbcBcFKX